Can you install a 36inch exit door at the end of 36inch corridor?
We are framing a small corridor (36 inch) and at the end of the corridor we want to have a 36 inch exit door towards the backyard for fire-escape and also for easier navigation to the backyard.
Is this possible?

You'd have to hinge the door outside the frame, opening outwards, or the door frame would reduce the opening to less than  36 inches. How you'd make that door seal and lock properly would be an issue you'd need to explore.

The door frame and the rough wall opening will be wider than 36 inches.  I would like a smaller door and have a few inches to play with.  I would do the door framing first, then build the corridor/hall.  To have close to max opening, the door should open outside.
